# Firebase hosting header firebase.json not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, cache-control

We are trying to set `Cache-control` in order to avoid aggressive caching by browsers. Unfortunately, we can't seem to get firebase to actually set this header. Here is our

`firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|webp|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|woff2)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=604800"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

We thought maybe our blob pattern matching was off so we have tried every combination you can imagine. `**/*`, `**/`, `/**`, etc. We can't figure out why these headers are not being applied. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the above actually works. It's just that chrome was caching the responses (the very thing we were trying to fix). When testing this make sure to use incognito mode.

Comment: if Chrome is still caching, for what reason there is Cache-Control? Is there a way to make sure that the user gets the newest version?